# Azure Event Grid Topic Logs - Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'AegPublishFailureLogs'

Tags: azure, azure-eventgrid

As shown in the picture, when I try to access the build-in log for "Publish failures by topic and error" of event grid topic, I got this error:

**Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'AegPublishFailureLogs'**

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHGaP.png)

It is the built-in query, anyone knows why?

Following is my Diagnostic Setting, I have checked "Send to Log Analytics workspace"

[Diagnostic setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGVTh.png)

Comment: The diagnostic is not enabled by default, so you should enable it first. However even with the archive to container and send to log analytics workspace it still gives the same error... Also interested to get this one solved.

Comment: experiencing the same

Comment: Any luck? Same here.

Comment: @BradLucas we just updated our on-prime azure devop server, looks like the problem is gone